# How do I send a message to a specific client(JAVA)

Tags: java

I want to send a message to a specific client:

```
/w hey there.
X:(priv)Y:hey there(what X sees in the console)
```

This is my code.When I type it like the upper example nothing shows neither on the specific client's console neither on the server.I don't understand why,because I also have a list of users that are connect in the Server class.

```
     import java.net.*;
     import java.io.*;

  public class ServerPeer extends Thread{
     Socket _socket;

   public ServerPeer(Socket _socket) {
    this._socket = _socket;
}
    public  void sendMessage(String _username,String _message) throws IOException {
    ObjectOutputStream _obj = new ObjectOutputStream(
            _socket.getOutputStream());
    _obj.writeObject(new Message(_username, _message));
    _obj.flush();

}

public synchronized void run()  {
try
    {   ObjectInputStream _ois = new ObjectInputStream(_socket.getInputStream());
    Message _message;
    while (_socket.isConnected()) {

               _message = (Message) _ois.readObject();
                    String divide=_message.getAll().substring(0,_message.getAll().indexOf(":"));
        for(ServerPeer sp:Server.listofpeers)
            {  
                 if(_message.getAll().startsWith("exit"))
                    {
                        _socket.close();Server.listofpeers.remove(sp);
                    }

              if(  !(_message instanceof PrivateMessage))
              {
                  sp.sendMessage(divide,_message.getAll());


                  System.out.println( _message.getAll());
              }  

              else

                   {
                       PrivateMessage privatem=(PrivateMessage)_message;
                       String receiver=privatem.getReceiver();
                       for(String s:Server.listofusers)
                       {
                           if(s.equals(receiver))
                           {
                               sp.sendMessage(divide,privatem.getAll());
                             System.out.println(privatem.getAll());
                               break;
                           }

                       }
                   }

            }    
        _ois = new ObjectInputStream(_socket.getInputStream());


        }

   }catch(IOException e){e.printStackTrace();}
    catch(ClassNotFoundException e){e.printStackTrace();}
       }
   }
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors or is it just not doing what you expect it to?

Comment: @Ascalonian not getting any errors,it's just not sending the message I suspect.I just don't find where I have mistaken.

Comment: up again............

Comment: What do you mean "up again"?

Comment: updated some things.Still doesn't work.

Comment: Are you ever [starting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#start()) the thread? And *never* make its `run()` method `synchronized` as that means asking for trouble…

Comment: @Holger yes the thread starts in another class.